# "Little to none" with countable nouns? Or "few to none"?

Tags: word-usage

I don't think this kind of question has been asked before, so here it is. I stumbled upon this particular sentence :
*

> "The problem here is that we are left with little to none cultural
> defences against any force which would want to conquer us."

- 

Since the word "**defence**" in this particular case is countable, I wonder if the correct expression is actually "**few** to none" instead of "**little**" in this context. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit to tell us the source of this sentence.  Was it in a book, or a blog or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't "little", it's "none". You can't say "none defences". This is fine:

> The problem here is that we are left with little to no cultural defences...

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is "little to no", and it applies best to non-countable nouns but possibly to countable nouns too.  This is the "proximity" rule, where the closer word tends to determine agreement.

So we can say

> There are a few apples left

> There are no apples left

We can't say

> There are little apples left (unless we mean the remaining apples are small)

But we can say

> There are little to no apples left.

But it might be better to say

> There are few if any apples left.

> There may be no more apples.

Or some other rephrasing

In the particular example,  the simplest way to improve the phrasing is just to use "defence" as an uncountable noun:

> The problem here is that we are left with little to no cultural defence against any force which would want to conquer us.

Comment: I'm most likely to use the phrase [**few if any**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/few%20if%20any), as in, "There are **few if any** apples left."